# Insert text at the beginning of each line from 2 to end - 5

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to insert a word followed by a tab character at the start of each line in a file (in-place insertion) but starting from line number 2 to all the lines but last 5 lines.

So if a file has 10 lines, I want to insert from line number 2 to line number 5 - I want to keep lines 1 and 6-10 intact in this case.

The file can have lines in millions (currently upto 10 million)

```
sed -i "s/^/word\t/" filename
```

The above works, but I want to insert on the first and last 5 lines. Also given a line range, calculating the number of lines will be another operation. Since the line numbers can vary, this extra operation can become an overhead. Looking for an efficient solution. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
COUNT=$((`wc -l test_csnap_delta.csv | cut -d ' ' -f 1` - 5))
sed -n -i '2,$COUNT s/^/word\t/'
```

However the above is deleting the entire file data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sed -i` does not do in-place insertion.  It creates a new file.

Comment: The command sed -i "s/^/word\t/" filename will add the text "word" followed by a tab character at the beginning of each line in the file named "filename", at least that is the end-result.

Comment: This feels more like a "programming assignment" rather than a "programming question".. This smells funny and i'm not going to eat it!

Comment: Gung Foo - Fair enough. I have been trying different things. Let me give where I was stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works without precounting the number of lines in the file:

```
sed -ni '1{p;b}; 2{N;N;N;N}; $p; $!{N;s/^/word /;P;D}' filename
```

This buffers five lines and makes the substitution on the first line in the buffer and prints and deletes it. When the last line in the file is read, the buffer is printed without doing any substitutions.

- `1{p;b}` - read the first line, print it unchanged and branch to the end
- `2{N;N;N;N}` - when line 2 is read, append four more lines to create a five-line buffer
- `$p` - when the last line of the file is read, print the lines that remain in the buffer unchanged
- `$!` - when the current line is not the last line in the file...
- `N` - append the next line to the buffer (pattern space)
- `s/^/word /` - make the substitution on the first line in the buffer
- `P` - print only the first line in the buffer
- `D` - delete only the first line in the buffer

Note that this won't work properly for files that consist of fewer than 6 lines.

This is the same idea using AWK:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print; next} FNR == 2 {for (ptr = 0; ptr <= 4; ptr++) {buffer[ptr] = $0; getline}; ptr = 0} {sub(/^/, "word ", buffer[ptr]); print buffer[ptr]; buffer[ptr] = $0; ptr = (ptr + 1) % 5} END {for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {print buffer[(ptr + i) % 5]}}' filename > outputfile
mv outputfile filename
```

Here it is broken out on multiple lines:

```
FNR == 1 {
    print
    next
}
FNR == 2 {
    for (ptr = 0; ptr <= 4; ptr++) {
        buffer[ptr] = $0
        getline
    }
    ptr = 0
}
{
    sub(/^/, "word ", buffer[ptr])
    print buffer[ptr]
    buffer[ptr] = $0
    ptr = (ptr + 1) % 5
}
END {
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        print buffer[(ptr + i) % 5]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis for an elaborative answer both using sed and awk. Helped me understand sed more.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
LINES=`wc -l filename | awk '{print $1}'`
awk -v lines=$LINES 'NR > 1 && NR < lines-5 {$0 = "word\t" $0} {print}' filename
```

If you want to modify `filename` instead of redirecting the output to a new file, you'll need a temporary file and some additional code to handle it:

```
mv filname tmpfile
LINES=`wc -l tmpfile | awk '{print $1}'`
awk -v lines=$LINES 'NR > 1 && NR < lines-5 {$0 = "word\t" $0} {print}' tmpfile \
  > filename
rm tmpfile
```

Basically, in-place editing is not the best of ideas (the programs that do in-place editing usually work on temporary files as well). If you're interested in the ugly details, have a look at [this article](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/).

Comment: Thanks Ansgar - I liked your version of getting line counts, I was using cut instead of awk and I think awk is better. However the awk is printing the lines. Here is what I had: 

    COUNT=$((wc -l filename | cut -d ' ' -f 1 - 5))
    sed -i -n'2,$COUNT s/^/word\t/' filename 

Though the above is completely deleting the data for some reason. – user866937 26 mins ago

Comment: @user866937: `LINES=$(wc -l < filename)` - if you use redirection with `wc` you don't need AWK or `cut`.

Comment: @DennisWlliamson Neat. Although I'd probably use `awk` anyway, because it's only proper to prepare a line-count for awk with awk as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed -i '1b;:a;$q;N;2,6ba;s/^/word\t/;P;D' file
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough RAM available, you could also try using `man 1 ed` (for more information on `ed` please see: [Editing files with the ed text editor from scripts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed)).

```
# using Bash

str="$(printf '%s\n' {1..10})"
tab="$(printf '\t')"

# test
cat <<EOF | ed -s <(echo "$str")
H
2,\$-5s/^/word${tab}/
,p
q
EOF

# in-place file editing
cat <<EOF | ed -s file
H
2,\$-5s/^/word${tab}/
wq
EOF
```