# Awk - print last 4 lines of the file

Tags: awk

I have a test file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

This command prints the last 4 lines of the file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{"wc -l < file" | getline b}{if(NR>b-4) print}' file
5 
6 
7 
8 
userpc@userpc-desktop
```

Now I want to do the same, but the command system ():

```
$ awk '{if( NR > (system("wc -l < file")-4) ) print}' file
8 
1 
8 
2 
8 
3 
8 
4 
8 
5 
8 
6 
8 
7 
8 
8 
userpc@userpc-desktop:
```

How to improve the last command system ()? I also want to print 4 last lines of the file.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You fork a `wc` **for each line** of the file??? Folks like you are the reason for 4GHz, Octocore CPUs with 64GB of RAM :-)

Comment: Oh, and it doesn't work because system() returns an exit status (0 in this case -> always true), not the output of wc. The stdout ("8") is printed for each line, as you can see.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but I still do not know how to improve the command system ().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`awk` is definitely not the right tool for this.  It's common to do: `sed '1{N;N;N;}; N; D; $p'`, and you can do something similar with awk:

```
awk '{for( i=0;i<3;i++) a[i]=a[i+1];a[3]=$0} END {print a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]}' OFS='\n'
```

Basically, you keep track of the last four lines seen, and print them all when you get to the end of the file.  You can be a little more obscure and efficient with:

```
awk '{a[++i%4]=$0} END {print a[++i%4],a[++i%4],a[++i%4],a[++i%4]}' OFS='\n'
```

but, really, why would you?

Comment: Good solution, but for printing a small number of lines. If I printed the more lines, the command will be longer.

Comment: Actually, this is a terrible solution!  But it does scale well if you use the second form with a for loop.  ie `awk '{a[++i%n]=$0} END {for(j=0;j<n;j++) print a[++i%n]}' n=256`

Comment: This solution is good. Yet I will wait for suggestions to improve my second command system ().

Comment: The solution in your comment would be the correct way to go. The principle is similar to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443105/insert-text-at-the-beginning-of-each-line-from-2-to-end-5/12450513#12450513).

Comment: but, really, why would you? For the same reasons you would want the first 4 lines of a file. This example pinpoints the limitations of awk as a general tool.

Comment: I don't think this exhibits limitations of awk so much as it demonstrates the flaw of thinking of streams as regular files.  You don't try to get the last four gallons of water from a river.

Comment: `sed` is the wrong solution too for any number more than single digits : `( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | gsed ; )  1.36s user 0.40s system 119% cpu 1.474 total
     97   43963. 29b490a426cf249805300b3b493b048b  stdin; ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | awktail -n 97; )  1.06s user 0.44s system 117% cpu 1.271 total
29b490a426cf249805300b3b493b048b  stdin`

Answer (score 14):

No need for awk, use `tail`:

```
$ tail -4 your_file
```

Comment: Thank you, good answer, but the question is about awk, and the last command.

Comment: Why complicated when an easy solution exists?

Comment: Thank proposals for solutions.

Comment: A practical solution in the general case could be to pipe the output from tail to awk:
tail -4 file | awk '{print}'
where "print" could be some more useful awk expression.

Answer (score 7):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '{ array[NR]=$0 } END { for (i=NR-3; i<=NR; i++) print array[i] }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Thank proposals for solutions.

Comment: @Steve : hmmm …. what `gawk` specific feature does it use that other `awk`s lack ? I'm not seeing any

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a mechanism to improve your use of `wc` inside `system`, try:

```
awk 'NR > count-4' count=$( wc -l < file ) file
```

To do this more within awk;

```
awk 'NR==1{ c="wc -l < " FILENAME; c | getline count } NR > count-4' input
```

This uses NR==1 instead of BEGIN because FILENAME is not defined inside a BEGIN block.
Note that neither of these use `system` from within awk, because there is no good way to get the output from `system`, but you can do ugly things like:

```
awk 'NR==1 { system( "wc -l > tmpfile < " FILENAME ); getline count < "tmpfile" }
    NR > count - 4' input
```

I cannot emphasize enough that this is merely an academic exercise.  Do not use awk for this!

Comment: Thank proposals for solutions.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : for `tail` maybe the core utilities have a slight advantage. For head, `gnu-head` loses by quite a lot : `( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | mawk2 '+__<NR{exit}__' FS='^$' __=10000000; )  1.25s user 0.48s system 118% cpu 1.463 total
721d7f270ce3eba05e57ec5e3a021675  stdin; ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | ghead -n 10000000; )  1.46s user 1.14s system 122% cpu 2.118 total
721d7f270ce3eba05e57ec5e3a021675  stdin`

Answer (score 4):

`tail` is the right tool, but if you want to see it done in Awk:

```
awk '{b=b RS $0} b~/(\n.*){4}/{sub(/[^\n]*\n/,"",b)} END{print b}'
```

1. Append line to buffer, separated by newline;
2. If there are 4 newlines in buffer, remove first line from it;
3. At end, print buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way using `tac` and `awk`:

```
$ tac file | awk 'NR==5{exit}1' | tac
5
6
7
8
```

- `tac` to reverse the file.
- `awk` to print first 4 lines and exit (good to have if your file is very large)
- `tac` to reverse the file again

Comment: Technically, you are still using awk, in conjunction with another tool which I find acceptable and helpful  - much easier to both remember and to type.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==5, NR==8{print NR} file
```

Prints from like 5th to the 8th line

Answer (score 0):

This solution using awk is a bit more verbatim, but it avoids string  operations by using a ring buffer.

It works as  a one-liner, but I formatted it for readability. Substitute `l` in the begin block for the number of lines you want.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
         l=4; i=0
     }
     {
         b[i]=$0;
         i=(i+1)%l
     }
     END {
         for(j=i; j < l; j++)
         {
             print b[j]
         } 
         for(j=0; j < i; j++)
         {
             print b[j]
         }
     }'
```

Answer (score 0):

unless your file is *much* larger than `2GB`, `1.84 secs` for this `1.85GB` test file should be reasonably fast enough without having to keep updating the same 4 cells in an array :

```
( time ( pvE0 < "${m3t}" | 

 {m,g}awk 'BEGIN {  __ = _ += _+= _^= FS = OFS = ORS 
                    RS = "^$"
                     _ = "\17\24\31"
                ORS = ___
           } NF<__ || sub("^",_,$(NF-__))+sub(("^.+")_,___)' ) | 

pvE9 ) | wc5 | lgp3


      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [3.08GiB/s] [3.08GiB/s] [========>] 100%            
     out9: 5.86KiB 0:00:01 [3.22KiB/s] [3.22KiB/s] [ <=> ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | mawk2 ; ) 


0.73s user 1.12s system 100% cpu 1.843 total

rows       = 4. | UTF8 chars = 2167. | bytes      = 6005.
```